# adding a click event to an image based on having data attributes

Tags: jquery

I have the following images:-

```
<img rel="item-1" src="1.gif"/>
<img rel="item-2" src="2.gif"/>
<img rel="item-3" src="3.gif"/>
```

and at the moment I can use Jquery to attach a click event to each image like so:-

```
$("img[rel^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```

Suppose I want to use the data attribute and remove the rel attribute:-

```
<img data-thumb="item-1" src="1.gif"/>
<img data-thumb="item-2" src="2.gif"/>
<img data-thumb="item-3" src="3.gif"/>
```

What would my jquery look like to attach a click event to each image that has the data-thumb attribute?

**EDIT** Sorry guys it is the same, like an idiot I forgot to change this in my code:-

`var url = img.attr('rel');` to `var url = img.data('thumb');`

I feel ashamed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same :)

```
$("img[data-thumb^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You replace `rel` in your selector with `data-thumb`:

```
$("img[rel^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```

becomes

```
$("img[data-thumb^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
$("img[data-thumb^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt the same work?

```
$("img[data-thumb^='item']").click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
});
```